# firewalld - where are the numeric firewall port numbers mapped to the service name?

Tags: services, firewalld, port

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=nfs
# filewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=rpc-bind
```

in RHEL/CentOS 7.9 if I do the above, what numeric port numbers are opened in the firewall?

Where is the mapping of service names (e.g. rpc-bind) to firewall port number defined?

Am I correct in believing that in `/etc/firewalld/zones/myzone.xml` that ultimately everything reduces to the following?

Being either `tcp` or `udp` and a number?

```
# sshd
  <port protocol="tcp" port="22"/>
# nfs
  <port protocol="tcp" port="2049"/>
  <port protocol="udp" port="2049"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: compiled into firewalld, see source.

Long answer: please take a look at [the README in the source code repository of firewalld](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/blob/master/README).

All services used by `firewalld` are defined in the `config/services` directory, in xml files. For example, the `rpc-bind.xml` file contains:

**edit:** in rhel/centos 7 that location is `/usr/lib/firewalld/services` for the xml files.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>rpc-bind</short>
  <description>Remote Procedure Call Bind</description>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="111"/>
  <port protocol="udp" port="111"/>
</service>
```

which pins rpc-bind to tcp and udp ports 111. Similarly, NFS (`nfs`, v4) looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>NFS4</short>
  <description>The NFS4 protocol is used to share files via TCP networking. You will need to have the NFS tools installed and properly configure your NFS server for this option to be useful.</description>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="2049"/>
</service>
```

and NFSv3 (`nfs3`) like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>NFS3</short>
  <description>The NFS3 protocol is used to share files. You will need to have the NFS tools installed and properly configure your NFS server for this option to be useful.</description>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="2049"/>
  <port protocol="udp" port="2049"/>
</service>
```

You ask about SSH as well:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>SSH</short>
  <description>Secure Shell (SSH) is a protocol for logging into and executing commands on remote machines. It provides secure encrypted communications. If you plan on accessing your machine remotely via SSH over a firewalled interface, enable this option. You need the openssh-server package installed for this option to be useful.</description>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="22"/>
</service>
```

These XML definitions are compiled into firewalld.